# Monte Carlo (variance reduction)

Tags: monte-carlo

Suppose we are to estimate

$$
I = \int_0^1e^xdx
$$

---

Suppose $Y$ random variable of density $f(x)=x+1, \ \ x \in [0,1]$.

$$
Z = \frac{e^Y}{1+Y}
$$

We know that $E(Z)=I$.

The question is :

How can we use the variable $Z$ in order to reduce the variance ?

I would appreciate if someone could give any help.Thank you very much !

Comment: is this part of a test, homework or exercise? If so please add the self-study tag.

Comment: _Hint:_ check the control variate entry in your Monte Carlo textbook.